# Adding a Section for Visitors

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, loop, multisite

I habe a basic dog care website where I would like to have a lost dog section where visitors can post about their lost dogs with pictures and custom fields like communication and location info. But they should not have access to edit blogpost and other article pages.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This forum is to get answers to (technical) problems, whereas you are asking for opinions.

The "challenge" you're having can be solved in different ways.

For starters the comment form could be used and it should be possible to add additional fields. See `add_comment_meta()` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta)

Another way could be to add use a form to gather the additional data and then find a way to output that data on the post/page.